# Clone external hard drive to internal hard drive

Tags: hard-drive

The hard drive failed on my new laptop so I installed Ubuntu 14.04.2 on an external hard drive and have been using it for the past 3 months. Now that the laptop manufacturer had sent me a new hard drive I want to clone whats on external hard drive to the internal hard disk. 
I'm looking for steps to take to do this correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use dd, from a live CD open a terminal an type:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=64K
```

Just replace /dev/sda with your external hardrive name and /dev/sdb with your internal hardrive name.

Comment: for future reference, I would add that this may fail if the external drive is larger. I would use gparted to shrink the partitions and then reexpand them on the new harddrive

Answer (score -1):

@user2308612 is right. You can use dd for this task. It does low level copy, the partitions will remain. You asked for step by step instructions and I think they are nicely written here (pictures included): http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19141/clone-a-hard-drive-using-an-ubuntu-live-cd/

Comment: Alternative method: https://www.linux.com/learn/clone-your-ubuntu-installation-new-hard-disk